# How do you create a log of create_autonomy published messages?

Tags: ros, irobot-create

I'm completely new to robotics and software as a hobby. I've got my irobot create2 up and running and I'm trying to create a log file for specific messages in "create_autonomy" https://github.com/AutonomyLab/create_autonomy.

I'm hoping to log this once a minute in the terminal window or a .txt file

- hour:minute:second    battery/charge 
  (95%)
- hour:minute:second   joint_states        (forward, 1.5
  mph)

Any ELI5 help would be awesome, I'm not sure where to start

This video ends at what I'm trying to do
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T4KRgNBRA2U&t=9s

Answer (score 1):

,

there is a standard tool for that: rosbag, it can record any message on the ROS network, you can take a look at the following link to see its usage

http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag